# Any mechanism to prevent rep farming with no-brainer editing?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

I've just came from the `Suggested Edits` review queue of StackOverflow because I found an user who was farming reputation with no-brainer editing. The reason why I referred it as "farming"  and "no-brainer" it's because all his editing is just simply removing "**Thanks in Advance**" at the end of every old post he can find.

Personally, I don't think simply removing "**Thanks in Advance**" is an acceptable editing. While such kinds of post with "**Thanks in Advance**" are not encouraged in SO, it's still worth notice that most authors of these posts are newcomers and it's understandable that they just want to show their gratitude to this site. So I have rejected all his suggested edits under the reason `no improvement whatsoever`.

When I checked his profile, I saw his daily rep gain by removing "**Thanks in Advance**". Apparently, still some of reviewers think that's an valid editing but daily **+106** rep all by removing "**Thanks in Advance**" is hilarious.

### (After I post this question, it's **+196** now...)

[image]

I wonder if there's any way to stop this kind of no-brainer suggested edits? The present mechanism doesn't seem to work well on this case.

---

## Update

Thanks for Roombatron5000's comment about +1000 editing rep cap mechanism. From this case, I feel this 1000 rep could be easily farmed by Googling `StackOverflow` + `(tag)` + `Thanks in Advance` and start no-brainer editing.

This action was also referred as "***edit-hunting***" in this MetaSO question: ["*Edit hunting and possible reputation farming - how should I react?*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260268/edit-hunting-and-possible-reputation-farming-how-should-i-react)

Comment: Related: [No Thanks, Damn it!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/1270504) That's the post where this user likely (incorrectly) concluded that these edits would be appropriate.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213184/286216) might be related.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 My point is: allowing gaining 100+ rep with this no-brainer action is unfair to other people who spend their time really answer questions.

Comment: @Tay2510 There is a maximum of like 1000 rep that you could earn from suggested edits. If the user isn't improving everything in the posts and the reviewers are still approving the suggested edits, that is the reviewers fault. If they'd reject and edit them correctly , then the user would get suspended from suggesting.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239143/if-rep-farming-with-edits-is-a-problem-why-offer-the-reputation-for-edits-in-th and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Roombatron5000 I know SE/SO offer rep for incentive reason, and I agree with it. But that's for better quality of the posts, not for people gaming the system. If someone know reviewer's taste like in case (edits removing TIA will mostly be accepted), he can just Google the keywords and edit all the posts. It's just like a legal loophole exploited by people. (I rejected all his suggested edit but he still got +186 now...)

Comment: @Tay2510 I think you misunderstood Roombatron. He can keep going but once he gets 1000 rep from edit he will earn no more. That is the mechanism in place to keep someone from farming too much rep from editing

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah, that's the mechanism. +1000 rep It's hard to reach for those who really spend time on editing what needs to be edited. But if people just Google `StackOverlfow` + `(tags)` + `Thanks in Advance` and easily gain 200+ reputation daily by no-brainer editing, it will look like a free farming of 1000 rep. Anyway, thank you and thanks Roombatron5000, I'll study the related thread about this issue.

Comment: I've found a related question in MetaSO here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260268/edit-hunting-and-possible-reputation-farming-how-should-i-react. It's called "**edit-hunting**".

Answer (score 5):

While I would prefer to see more than a removal of "Thanks in advance" in a suggested edit, I would argue that such edits are nevertheless valuable to reinforce early that there is "no chit chat" in Stack Exchange questions and answers.

This point is reinforced in the paragraph below from [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here):

> once you realize that it's not just about the one asker, or the four
>   voters, but rather the fifteen thousand searchers with the same
>   problem... Well, suddenly, a whole ton of things that seem prickly and
>   self-important, like editing out "Thanks in advance!" aren't about
>   being "a bunch of power-happy pedants," they're about helping all the
>   people who will ever have that problem to find the best answers. And
>   find 'em instant-like.

Comment: I think its different in different SE sites , [Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9653) people dont mind Thank you .

Comment: @ysts2 I'm all for politeness in comments, and politeness in life, but in Q&As it just seems like more to read.

Comment: True , I am just stating that your generalization - _in Stack Exchange questions and answers_ may not be true for all SE sites .